# Why do simple carburetors richen the mixture as altitude increases?

Tags: carburetor

(Question copied largely verbatim from https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/59328/why-do-carburetors-tend-to-produce-richer-mixture-at-higher-altitude. I have the identical question and it's really eating at me!)

Simple first-principles analysis of fluid dynamics suggest that the pressure driving fuel into a carburetor venturi should change linearly with air density.

The pressure drop across the venturi is proportional to air density and the fuel is at ambient pressure in the float chamber, so I would expect the fuel flow to reduce proportionally with density, and that response to preserve the fuel-air ratio over changing altitude.

But in practice that does not seem to be the case. Proper response to altitude requires additional modification that most airplane carburetors don't have, so the pilot usually has to manually lean out the engine during the climb. What am I missing here?

More specifically, I would expect that at the same RPM, the volume flow rate will be the same—because the engine pulls in its displacement per revolution. Now velocity in the venturi $v$ is just

$$ v = \frac{\dot V}{A} $$

Where $\dot V$ is the volume flow rate and $A$ is the cross-section of the venturi. So it will also be the same independent of altitude. Since dynamic pressure

$$ P_d = \frac 1 2 \rho v^2 $$

And that is also the pressure that pulls in the fuel (when the float chamber is open to ambient pressure). Substituting mass flow

$$ \dot m = \rho v $$
$$ P_d = \dot m \frac 1 2 v $$

and as long as $v$ is mostly constant,

$$ P_d \sim \dot m $$

So in other words, the pressure which drives the fuel through the jets and into the venturi varies somewhat linearly with the mass of air going through the carburetor. This would suggest that the fuel/air ratio will stay relatively constant... which of course is the opposite of observed behavior.

So this leaves open the dependence of fuel flow on $P_d$. If the relation is reasonably close to linear, it should mean the venturi mixes properly by mass. I can see a reason why higher pressure should cause less than linear increase in fuel flow, but not much why it should cause more than linear increase in fuel flow—but that is what the actual behavior would need.

Comment: linear doesn't mean directly proportional.

Comment: Why would the fuel density change?

Comment: @SolarMike only air density changes with altitude. I clarified the question.

Comment: So, what did you not understand from the answers posted? seems clear enough...

Comment: @SolarMike so far, there is no answer in any of the "answers" posted on SE.Aviation. They simply repeat what we are taught as student pilots, without any understanding of the physics driving the phenomenon. I know I have to adjust my mixture as I climb, but I don't know why the carburetor changes the fuel/air ratio with altitude. It is not a simple case of the carburetor always pumping the same amount of fuel per engine stroke. The ratio of venturi to float bowl pressures are changing in some non-trivial way and that understanding remains elusive.

Comment: There are 3 answers given to the question you link to. Also, the carb does not do any "pumping", you need to check what the venturi does.

Comment: All three answers are either incorrect or answering a different question than was asked. It's challenging and subtle. P.S. I think we have different definitions of pumps, as I consider any pressure differential in fluid resulting in a flow a "pump". The sole reason for the venturi is to provide a difference in pressure across the jet, which in turn forces/pumps/pushes liquid into the venturi body.

Comment: @SolarMike I figured it out, the answer is below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; It's complex, I don't have a simple physical description. It basically comes down to the fuel-air ratio being a function of the square root of pressure whereas air mass is simply proportional to pressure. Maybe someone can add an intuitive explanation in the comments?

---

### Preface

I figured it out. The answer is subtle and requires a decent dive into the math behind fluid flow.

### Simple carburetor

Let's consider the constant throttle setting of the below carb:

[image: Ideal flow system of a simple float carburetor]

For simplicity, we will assume both engine RPM and ambient temperature are constant.

We will also assume that the system has no [head losses](https://engineeringlibrary.org/reference/head-loss-fluid-flow-doe-handbook).

### Fluid dynamics

#### Liquid

An ideal liquid has no viscosity and its density is constant. Through the Bernoulli Equation, the ideal flow of such a liquid through a passage can be written as:

$$ \dot{m_l} = A_l \rho_l u_l = A_l \sqrt{2 \rho_l \Delta P_l} $$

where

- $m_l$ is the liquid mass flow
- $\Delta P_l = P_{01,l} - P_{2,l}$
- $\rho_l$ is the fluid density
- $u_l$ is the fluid velocity
- $A_l$ is the flow area (in this case, the carburetor jet)

#### Gas

Using Bernouilli, the equation for an ideal gas is almost the same:

$$ \dot{m_g} = A_g \rho_g u_l \phi_g = A_g \phi_g \sqrt{2 \rho_g \Delta P_g} $$

where subscripts have changed from `l` to `g` and:

- $\phi_g$ is the gas flow compressibility parameter

### Fuel/air ratio

#### Definition

We'll assume air is an ideal gas, and that the liquid is gasoline. (I apologize in advance for the fact that *gas* can mean both a phase of matter and a shortened version of "gasoline". Throughout this answer, I will use *gas* to mean only a phase of matter and *gasoline* only for petroleum fuel.)

$$ F_M = \frac{\dot{m_l}}{\dot{m_g}}  = \frac{A_l \sqrt{2 \rho_l \Delta P_l}}{A_g \phi_g \sqrt{2 \rho_g \Delta P_g}} $$

where:

- $F_M$ is the fuel/air ratio

#### Simplification

Simplifying this expression by eliminating variables, abstracting out the constant coefficients $A_l$, $A_g$, and $\rho_l$, and-- most importantly-- noting that the pressure differential $\Delta P_l$ and $\Delta P_g$ are identical (because in the case of the ideal carburetor both go from the air inlet to the venturi body:

$$ F_M \propto \frac{1}{\phi_g \sqrt{\rho_g}} $$

#### Analysis at different pressures, i.e altitudes

Let's look at thee $F_M$ at two different pressures, $P_0$ and $P_1$:

- $ F_{M,0} \propto \frac{1}{\phi_{g,0} \sqrt{\rho_{g,0}}} $
- $ F_{M,1} \propto \frac{1}{\phi_{g,1} \sqrt{\rho_{g,1}}} $

Dividing these two, and noting that the coefficients eliminated in the `Simplification` step now fully cancel out, resulting in equality:

$$ \frac{ F_{M,0}}{F_{M,1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{\phi_{g,0} \sqrt{\rho_{g,0}}}}{\frac{1}{\phi_{g,1} \sqrt{\rho_{g,1}}}} = \frac{\phi_{g,1} \sqrt{\rho_{g,1}}}{\phi_{g,0} \sqrt{\rho_{g,0}}}$$

I won't go into the derivation of $\phi$, but suffice to say that for the conditions given in the `Simple carburetor` section, it is constant at all altitude. This results in the very simple equation:

$$ \frac{ F_{M,0}}{F_{M,1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\rho_{g,1}}{\rho_{g,0}}}$$

### Conclusion

Assuming that condition 0 is at altitude, condition 1 is the sea level reference, and that density, $\rho$, is a linear function of pressure, the ratio of the fuel mass flow at seal level to the fuel mass flow at altitude is:

$$ \frac{ F_{M,alt}}{F_{M,S.L}} = \sqrt{\frac{P_{S.L}}{P_{alt}}}$$

Compare this to the ratio of air mass flow at altitude and note the lack of square roots:

$$ \frac{ \dot{m_{g,alt}}}{\dot{m_{g,S.L}}} = \frac{P_{alt}}{P_{S.L}}$$

This is why the ratios get out of whack as altitude changes.

#### Worked example

What is the richening percentage going from sea level on an STP day to 5000m (assuming perfect dry adiabatic lapse)?

At 5000m, according to  https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator this is 54kPa, or ~0.5atm.

$$ \sqrt{\frac{P_{S.L.}}{P_{alt}}} = \sqrt{\frac{101}{54}} = 1.37 $$

So the carburetor is pushing a `37%` richer mixture than at sea level.

**NOTE** that this is *not* the `50%` which would happen if the carb simply pumped in the same amount of fuel for every engine stroke, no matter the air density.

Comment: I have always found that when you are close enough to asking an intelligent question, you are close to the answer.  Good job!